# Compare alternate lines in two files in unix using grep

Tags: unix, if-statement, grep

I am trying to compare two files using unix and return success (if file1 contents match with file2) or return failure if don't match and show the records that don't match

Contents of file1:

```
columnA1 columnA2
121     ab354664
columnB1 columnB2
143     be000431
ColumnC1 columnC2
001     21uy7732
```

Contents of file2:

```
columnA1 columnA2
121     ab354664
columnB1 columnB2
143     be000431
columnC1 columnC2
431     66575wqq
```

I have below code:

```
if (grep -v "column" $file1) == (grep -v "column" $file2)
then
    echo -e "match"
else
    echo -e "dont match"
    grep -B 1 -v "column" $file
fi
```

Its throwing the error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `=='
```

I am not sure if comparison operation can be used for comparing strings in two different files.

Please suggest.

Comment: You can use `==` in certain contexts to compare two string, but you don't have 2 strings!    But why don't you just do `diff file1 file2`?

Comment: Are you using `bash`? as your native shell or other?

Comment: yeah i use bash only

Answer (score 2):

Try below awk commands -

```
$ cat f1
columnA1 columnA2
121     ab354664
columnB1 columnB2
143     be000431
ColumnC1 columnC2
001     21uy7732
```

---

```
$ cat f2
columnA1 columnA2
121     ab354664
columnB1 columnB2
143     be000431
columnC1 columnC2
431     66575wqq
```

> cmd1: Print only Matched columns of f1 and f2

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$0;next}  ($1FS$2) in a {print  a[$1FS$2] " match"}' f2 f1
columnA1 columnA2 match
121     ab354664 match
columnB1 columnB2 match
143     be000431 match
```

> cmd2: Print Matched column of file f1 & f2 and non matched column of
>   file f1

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$0;next} {print (a[$1FS$2] ? a[$1FS$2] " match" : $0 " Do not")}' f2 f1
columnA1 columnA2 match
121     ab354664 match
columnB1 columnB2 match
143     be000431 match
ColumnC1 columnC2 Do not
001     21uy7732 Do not
```

EDIT1 : To ignore the lines which contain Column, use below -

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$0;next}  ($1FS$2) in a {if(a[$1FS$2] !~ /column/) {print a[$1FS$2] " match"}}' f2 f1
121     ab354664 match
143     be000431 match
```

EDIT2 : To print only non-match column -

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$0;next}  {print  (!a[$1FS$2]?$0:"")}' f1 f2



columnC1 columnC2
431     66575wqq
```

Comment: This works. i did some modification to match my req. and show only alternate lines  (i.e. exclude columns and compare lines having numbers. `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next} {(a[$2] ? a[$2] : print $0 " Do not")}' LL_CNT_Result_20170412_0743 LL_PD_Result_20170412_0743`. But i want print only non-matching lines in the output from file2. `columnC1 431  columnC2 66575wqq`. For which i did `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next} {( print a[$2] ? a[$2] :$0 "[$2]")}' f1 f2`. This gives me a syntax error

Comment: Thanks. but i am  trying to print non-matching lines only from file2 `column C1 columnC2 431 66575wqq` .. which seems to be confusing me again

Comment: @user1023627 - Check my updated answer Edit2, which print non-matching value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `diff` will do:

```
diff <(grep -vi column file1) <(grep -vi column file2)
```

Output:

```
3c3
< 001     21uy7732
---
> 431     66575wqq
```

Or if you want to use it with `if-then-else`:

```
if diff <(grep -vi column file1) <(grep -vi column file2) > /dev/null; then 
  echo Yes
else 
  echo No
fi
```

Output:

```
No
```

Comment: this works. but i want to print the non-matching entries from file2. i.e. `columnC1 columnC2
431     66575wqq`

Answer (score 0):

Here in an awk solution that prints which records present in a file are not present in the other:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {
           file1=FILENAME
           a[$0]++
           next
       }
       ($0 in a) && a[$0]>0 {
           a[$0]--
           next
       }
       {
           print $0 " not in " file1
       }
       END {
           for(i in a)
               if(a[i]>0)
                   print i " not in " FILENAME
       }' file1 file2
columnC1 columnC2 not in file1
431     66575wqq not in file1
001     21uy7732 not in file2
ColumnC1 columnC2 not in file2
```

Also, if `file1` has one record twice and `file2` only once, it is a mismatch. Output could be pretier...

Answer (score 0):

If you have two columns in each file you could zip them together with `paste` and then compare with `awk`, e.g.:

```
paste file1 file2 | 
awk 'NR%2 { h = $0 } !(NR%2) && ($1 != $3 || $2 != $4) { print h; print $0 }'
```

Output:

```
ColumnC1 columnC2   columnC1 columnC2
001     21uy7732    431     66575wqq
```